# "pointer passing convention" in UEFI module

Tags: c, uefi

I want to know when I need to free a pointer that is returned from EFI functions

```
EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL *
BmExpandFileDevicePath (
  IN  EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL    *FilePath,
  IN  EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL    *FullPath
  )
{
  EFI_STATUS                      Status;
  UINTN                           Index;
  UINTN                           HandleCount;
  EFI_HANDLE                      *Handles;
  EFI_BLOCK_IO_PROTOCOL           *BlockIo;
  UINTN                           MediaType;
  EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL        *NextFullPath;
  BOOLEAN                         GetNext;

  EfiBootManagerConnectAll ();
  Status = gBS->LocateHandleBuffer (ByProtocol, &gEfiSimpleFileSystemProtocolGuid, NULL, &HandleCount, &Handles);
  if (EFI_ERROR (Status)) {
    HandleCount = 0;
    Handles = NULL;
  }

  GetNext = (BOOLEAN)(FullPath == NULL);
  NextFullPath = NULL;
  //
  // Enumerate all removable media devices followed by all fixed media devices,
  //   followed by media devices which don't layer on block io.
  //
  for (MediaType = 0; MediaType < 3; MediaType++) {
    for (Index = 0; Index < HandleCount; Index++) {
      Status = gBS->HandleProtocol (Handles[Index], &gEfiBlockIoProtocolGuid, (VOID *) &BlockIo);
      if (EFI_ERROR (Status)) {
        BlockIo = NULL;
      }
      if ((MediaType == 0 && BlockIo != NULL && BlockIo->Media->RemovableMedia) ||
          (MediaType == 1 && BlockIo != NULL && !BlockIo->Media->RemovableMedia) ||
          (MediaType == 2 && BlockIo == NULL)
          ) {
        NextFullPath = AppendDevicePath (DevicePathFromHandle (Handles[Index]), FilePath);
        if (GetNext) {
          break;
        } else {
          GetNext = (BOOLEAN)(CompareMem (NextFullPath, FullPath, GetDevicePathSize (NextFullPath)) == 0);
          FreePool (NextFullPath);
          NextFullPath = NULL;
        }
      }
    }
    if (NextFullPath != NULL) {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (Handles != NULL) {
    FreePool (Handles);
  }

  return NextFullPath;
}
```

for example, In this code, can I free `Handles` after calling `HandleProtocol` and still be able to use `BlockIo`?
Is there a document that explains the "pointer passing convention" of edk2 functions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to look into the [specification](https://uefi.org/specifications), if you are responsible to free the pointer there is a note.

For your *LocateHandleBuffer* example:

> Buffer
>
> A pointer to the buffer to return the requested array of handles that
> support Protocol. This buffer is allocated with a call to the Boot
> Service EFI_BOOT_SERVICES.AllocatePool(). **It is the caller's
> responsibility to call the Boot Service EFI_BOOT_SERVICES.FreePool()
> when the caller no longer requires the contents of Buffer."**

You can use the BlockIO protocols after you free the buffer, you are not freeing the handle instances (which would be a very bad idea), instead you are freeing an array of them.